Ubuntu 244.10 - no sound, except bluetooth - help?
No sound, except by Bluetooth. Aarm64/Snapdragon X system - I fixed the package manager, but getting sound on the main system - already re-downloaded system 3 times - same issue - no sound.  Any suggestions?
